# URL Bookmarks resolving to multiple files

Tags: cocoa, nsurl, bookmarks

My app stores a large collection of file references in a database by using the URL Bookmark. These files are located on removable BD-R media, so once stored, the files are taken offline (by the nature of removable media).

I notice that a URL Bookmark to "File A" on BD-R A will sometime incorrectly resolve to "File B" on BD-R B once BD-R B is placed in the drive and made accessible.

This massively messes up the database and bookmarks are resolving to seemingly random files depending on what disc is currently online.

Comment: URL Bookmarks are a little bit of a black art, but basically there are multiple criteria a bookmark uses to try and find the original file. The two that are probably confusing it are the volume name and UUID (if any), and the file's ID (inode). For example, a bookmark sees a volume with the same name, no UUID, and a file path the doesn't match. But then it sees another file with the same node number, and assumes that must be it. (continued)

Comment: I'd first try turning off `NSURLBookmarkCreationPreferFileIDResolution` when creating the bookmark. But you might have to figure out a way of identifying each disc and only applying the bookmarks that came from that volume.